# Extract a sample from a Pandas DataFrame keeping all values of the same type

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge CSV which is made like this:

```
type, value
A     1
B     4
C     6
A     25
D     5
B     7
```

Since there are too many rows to be processed, I would like to take a sample, but the peculiarity of this sample has to be the following: all the rows of the same type have to be taken.

I started with taking a random sample of the rows:

```
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('file.csv') - 1
sample_lines = int(num_lines * 0.01)
skip = sorted(random.sample(range(num_lines), num_lines - sample_lines))
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';', skiprows=skip)
```

But this gives me only a *random sample of the rows*. What I would like to obtain is a *random sample of the types*.

I have the general process in mind:

1. Import the whole CSV in a Pandas DataFrame
2. Generate the (random) list of types to extract (e.g. [A, B])
3. Extract from the DataFrame only the rows with type 'A' or 'B'

The result should be something like this:

```
type  value
A     1
B     4
A     25
B     7
```

Thank you for any help you could give.

Comment: Did you try to load it to a DataFrame already and extract some rows?

Comment: @Dric512 please check my answer below, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a correct approach?

First, create the DataFrame by importing it from a CSV.
Then, creating the array which contains the list of all the possible types, and selecting only n of them (randomly).
And lastly, Saving a new DataFrame with only these n types (but with all the data related to them).

```
n = 10
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';')
random_types = np.random.choice(df.type.unique(), n)
m = df['type'].isin(random_types)
df_sample = df.loc[m]
```

This approach has the disadvantage that the entire CSV has to be loaded in memory, though.

**Full example**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(400)

data = '''\
type value
A     1
B     4
C     6
A     25
D     5
B     7'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj, sep='\s+')
n = 2
random_types = np.random.choice(df.type.unique(), n)
print(df.loc[df['type'].isin(random_types)])
```

Returns:

```
  type  value
0    A      1
3    A     25
4    D      5
```

Comment: Yes this is definately a good strategy. I'll make some modifications if that is alright.